# How can I convert a mesh.locallyTranslate Vector3 motion into a world space motion to give momentum to an object?

Tags: babylonjs

I have the following scene https://rawgit.com/bicarbon8/SpaceSim/MomentumProblem/babylon.html that I've setup with the ability to rotate using the following keys:

- i = pitch down
- k = pitch up
- j = roll left
- l = roll right
- u = yaw left
- o = yaw right
- / = cancel all rotation

and to move with the following keys:

- q = move forwards
- a = move backwards
- s = strafe left
- f = strafe right
- e = move up
- d = move down
- \ = cancel all movement

which is working fine to move the mesh in a direction that it is pointing, but I would like to initiate motion based on the rotation of the mesh, but then continue the movement in the original direction irrespective of the change in rotation to the mesh that happens after motion is initiated (maintain momentum).

I'm tracking the motion in each direction via a separate object with x, y, and z values so that each press of the keyboard for motion only modifies this object which is then applied to the mesh for each loop of the animation cycle, but because I'm using:

> mesh.locallyTranslate(new BABYLON.Vector3(x, y, z))

when the mesh is rotated the motion rotates with the mesh. How can I convert the directionality of the mesh's rotation into a Vector3 that I can use with World-based translation such that the subsequent rotation of the mesh does not affect the motion it already has?

NOTE: this should simulate motion in a microgravity / no gravity environment

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

managed to find a solution on my own through a combination of Unity engine and Three.js solutions to a similar type of problem followed by scouring the Babylon.js github pages. To fix it I had to change my globally tracked velocity object from a direct input based on key presses to a calculated BABYLON.Vector3 based on the mesh's World Matrix and a Normalised Vector3 for the local-space direction I wanted to move the mesh which is then added to the existing global Vector3 used to track the momentum (and is then subsequently applied to the mesh using World-space translation.

Original:

```
var direction = new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(); // global
...
// on keypress of 'q' key apply thrust along 'z' axis
if (map["q"]) { // forward thrust
  direction.z += 0.001;
};
...
// apply translation to mesh
mesh.locallyTranslate(new BABYLON.Vector3(x, y, z));
```

Fixed:

```
var velocity = new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero(); // global
...
// on keypress of 'q' key apply thrust along 'z' axis using mesh world matrix to convert to world space vector
if (map["q"]) { // forward thrust
  var matrix = mesh.getWorldMatrix();
  var vector = new BABYLON.Vector3.Zero();
  vector = BABYLON.Vector3.TransformNormal(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 1), matrix);
  velocity.addInPlace(vector);
};
...
// apply translation to mesh
mesh.translate(velocity, 0.001, BABYLON.Space.WORLD);
```

Now the 'velocity' object maintains momentum and the object is free to rotate and apply additional changes to the 'velocity' object based on its rotation and direction of thrust.

Example Code: https://rawgit.com/bicarbon8/SpaceSim/FixTranslationMomentum/babylon.html